# can't display data using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

Im using ajax to display data from controller.
My model :

```
public function DtOdontogram($id_pasien){
        $odontogram=$this->db->query("SELECT id_odontogram, id_pasien, gigi, posisi, kondisi FROM odontogram where id_pasien=$id_pasien");
        if ($odontogram->row_array()>0) {
            return $odontogram->result_array();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Controller

```
public function odontogram($id_pasien){
            $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->DataPerPasien($id_pasien)->result();
            $data['odontogram']=$this->m_pasien->DtOdontogram($id_pasien);
            $data['sidebar']='member/dokter/sidebar_psn';
            $data['content']='member/dokter/odontogram';
            $this->load->view('member/dokter/main',$data);
}
```

Ajax

```
function load(){
          $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/odontogram/');?>" + id_pasien,
              type:"GET",
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(data){
                if (data.status) {
                  console.log(data);
                  alert('succeess');
                  $.each(data,function(i,val){

                  $("#"+gigi).find("#"+posisi).css({fill: "#333333"});

              });
                }
              },
              error:function(){
                alert('error ... ');
                 }
                });
            }
load();
```

Its always display error message in alert. Can anyone help me? If I display it using json_encode in controller, it can get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `url` parameter to :

```
url:"\"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/odontogram/');?>" + id_pasien + '"',
```

and also the `id_pasien` is undefined, you have to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it by myself. I change the controller, separate between echo json encode and load view

```
$data['odontogram']=$this->m_pasien->DtOdontogram($id_pasien);
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
            {
              echo json_encode($data);
              exit;
            }
            $data['pasien']=$this->m_pasien->DataPerPasien($id_pasien)->result();
            $data['sidebar']='member/dokter/sidebar_psn';
            $data['content']='member/dokter/odontogram';
            $this->load->view('member/dokter/main',$data);
```